# Beamer table of contents custom bullets: Long section titles do not align

Tags: beamer, sectioning, table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment

I have redefined the table of contents bullets in my slides to a circled number. However, long section titles which span more than one line do not align with the text from the previous line but with the section number. How can I fix this?

Minimal working example

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{enumerate item}%
    \protect\circled{\inserttocsectionnumber}~\inserttocsection%
}

\begin{document}

\section{some really long title some really long title some really long title
         some really long title}

\begin{frame}{Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideallsubsections,subsubsectionstyle=hide]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi ilprincipe. It is always preferable to post complete [minimal working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) rather than code snippets because this helps people to answer you. You should also include the code needed to generate `\circled{}` for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was sufficiently simple. Have added a MWE.

Comment: Thank you for providing the MWE. Perhaps, the simplest solution is to exploit `\section[Short title that appears only in the toc]{Long title that appears in the frame}`. I'm sure we have some answer about this, but at the moment I'm not able to find them.

Comment: I am already exploiting that for the header. However, the second part in curly brackets is the one appearing in the table of contents. Also, this is for a presentation of a series of papers/projects, and not all titles can be shortened sufficiently.

Comment: this is most probably not the answer you are searching for, but if you put `\hspace{-16pt}` as the first thing inside of `circled[1]{` the text is aligned.

Comment: Would be ok as a dirty hack, but in my modified template this moves large parts of the number out off the text margin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following answer is based on

> beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty

Just switched the colours a bit and the linestyle

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{
    \leavevmode\leftskip=2ex%
    \llap{%
        \usebeamerfont*{section number projected}%
        \usebeamercolor{section number projected}%
        \begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{0ex}{1ex}{2ex}
            \color{bg}
            \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{.75ex}}{1.4ex}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
            \pgftext[base]{\color{bg}\inserttocsectionnumber}
        \end{pgfpicture}\kern1.25ex%
    }%
    \inserttocsection\par
}

\begin{document}

    \section{some really long title some really long title some really long title
        some really long title}

    \begin{frame}{Contents}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideallsubsections,subsubsectionstyle=hide]
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{enumerate item}%
    \makebox[2em][l]{\circled{\inserttocsectionnumber}}%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em}{\inserttocsection}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{some really long title some really long title some really long title
         some really long title}

\begin{frame}{Contents}
    blblblbl % to show the margin
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideallsubsections,subsubsectionstyle=hide]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```